# Change the location of a DOM element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have an angular directive which works similar to a carousel. In order to keep the dom element count down, I remove elements from the dom and re-insert them. I'm currently making use of the `angular.element` in order to select, delete and insert new items like so:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, elem){
            var jqLite = angular.element;

            var parentElement = jqLite(elem[0].queryselector('.parent'));

            // Selection..
            var oldElement = jqLite(elem[0].queryselector('.oldItem'));
            var newElement = jqLite('<div class=".newItem">Content here</div>');

            oldElement.remove();

            parentElement.append(newElement);

        }
    }
});
```

Basically this code finds `oldElement` and removes it and creates `newElement` and appends it to the parent container element. Basically I want to know if its possible *move* `oldElement` to a new location rather than deleting and creating a whole new element?

Comment: what you mean _move to a new location_? if you do `append(oldElement)` for some other element - it _moved_

Comment: You can hide the old element with ´ng-hide´ in DOM.

Comment: @Grundy thanks for the reply, I'll try it out

Comment: @mggSoft Thanks for the suggestion, however, I'm not interested in hiding elements in place. If for instance, the carousel has 200+ items, I'm not going to hide 195 rendered items

Comment: Ok @MatthewMerryfull. You can use `ng-if`, which allows you remove or add the item to DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly how [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) works (Node.prototype.appendChild). It moves element to new location if it's already in DOM tree, or creates new element and inserts to DOM if it's not there yet.

In your case:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            var jqLite = angular.element;

            var parentElement = jqLite(elem[0].querySelector('.parent'));
            var oldElement = jqLite(elem[0].querySelector('.oldItem'));

            parentElement.append(oldElement);
        }
    }
});
```

or rather, because you don't need jQuery/jqLite) for such a simple DOM trick:

```
link: function(scope, elem){
    var parentElement = elem[0].querySelector('.parent');
    var oldElement = elem[0].querySelector('.oldItem');
    parentElement.appendChild(oldElement);
}
```